# Python multiprocessing race condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, race-condition

I discovered a strange error when using `concurrent.futures` to read from multiple text files.

Here is a small reproducible example:

```
import os
import concurrent.futures

def read_file(file):
    with open(os.path.join(data_dir, file),buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            try:
                print(row)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data'))
    files = ['file1', 'file2']
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for file,_ in zip(files,executor.map(read_file,files)):
            pass
```

`file1` and `file2` are arbitrary text files in the `data` directory.

I am getting the following error (basically a process tries to read `data_dir` variable before it is assigned):

```
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 175, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 153, in _process_chunk
    return [fn(*args) for args in chunk]
  File "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 153, in <listcomp>
    return [fn(*args) for args in chunk]
  File "C:\Users\my_username\Downloads\example.py", line 5, in read_file
    with open(os.path.join(data_dir, file),buffering=1000) as f:
NameError: name 'data_dir' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 16, in <module>
    for file,_ in zip(files,executor.map(read_file,files)):
  File "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 556, in result_iterator
    yield future.result()
  File "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 405, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
NameError: name 'data_dir' is not defined
```

If I place `data_dir` assignment before `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, I don't get this error and the code executes as expected.

What is causing this error? Clearly, `data_dir` is assigned before any asynchronous calls should be made in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fork()` not available on windows, so python use `spawn` to start new process, which will start a fresh python interpreter process, no memory will be shared, but python will [try to recreate](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L92-L118) worker function environment in the new process, that's why module level variable works. See [doc for more detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I remember that this code ran fine on my Macbook yesterday, so getting this error today on a Windows machine was pretty confusing.

Comment: you are welcome! @MaxLawnboy I also learned there is a `concurrent` lib in python3.

Answer (score 3):

`ProcessPoolExecutor` spaws a new Python **process**, imports the right module and calls the function you provide.
As `data_dir` will only be defined when you *run* the module, not when you *import* it, the error is to be expected.

Providing the `data_dir` file descriptor as an argument to `read_file` *might* work, as I believe that processes inherit the file descriptors of their parents. You'd need to check, though.

If were to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` however, your example should work, as the spawned threads share memory.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to pass additional arguments to the function used by `executor.map()`. I guess the only way to get it to work on a Windows is to define `data_dir` on the module level.

Comment: Good point. I guess you could modify the called function to accept a tuple as its only parameter and pack your actual arguments into it if you really need to use `map`.